# Azure Web Site stopped working because of timeouts on SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, azure, website

My site is crashed unexpectedly after several months of smoothly work. I haven't done any site updates or re-configuration. But for last 14 hours I have the following situation:

1. When site is up and tried to connect to Azure SQL Database timeout exception appeared in EventLog.xml:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

(whole message you can [read there](http://justpaste.it/qa13))

2. In diagnostics I can see the following error for another SQL operation:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>          at SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SNI_ConnWrapper* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
>          at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)

(whole message you can [read there](http://justpaste.it/qa11))

I can successfully connect to the DB using SQL Management Studio from my laptop and perform any query without timeouts.

Comment: Not that this will necessarily help, but can you please clarify if you're using SQL Database service, vs SQL Server in a VM?

Comment: I am not sure that understand your comment clearly :) I am using Azure SQL Database. On the same instance of SQL Server I have one more database with similar structure for testing purposes. The testing web site is also Azure Web Site and it is working properly. In development environment the same system with DB in VM is working too. So I have no idea

Comment: I *think* you just answered my question. I was asking if you were using Azure's SQL Database **service** or if you were using SQL Server on your own virtual machine. Sounds like you're using the service. Through Azure App Service (Web App, formerly known as Web Sites). Just trying to clarify, for those trying to help you.